# DASH Realtime candlestick chart wont update, websocket, sqlalchemy, flask app

Tags: python, flask, websocket, real-time, plotly-dash

i have this flask app connected with dash, where i get data from a python binance websocket, and convert it to sql.

The SQL code from the websocket stream looks like this:

```
res1hf.to_csv('Crypto.csv', header=False)
rec = pd.read_csv('Crypto.csv')
rec.to_sql('crypto', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

I then run the websocket in terminal to keep getting a stream updated to the Database, and it updates just as its suppose to.

However when i apply it to my DASH app it just wont live update the Graph.
It updates if i refresh the page, but besides that it doesnt do much else.

The code for the Flask/Dash/Waitress app is this:

```
import plotly
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import flask
import waitress
from waitress import serve


server = flask.Flask(__name__) # define flask app.server

app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server) # call flask server


rec = pd.read_sql_table('crypto', engine)
  
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph-scatter', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            disabled=False,
            interval=1*1000,
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
)

@app.callback(Output('live-update-graph-scatter', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_interval')])
def update_graph_scatter(n):

    def updatesql(n):
        rec1 = pd.DataFrame(rec)
        rec1.columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']

        rec1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(rec1['date'])
        rec1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        print(rec1)
        return rec1
    rec1 = updatesql(n)


    data = plotly.graph_objects.Candlestick(
        x=rec1.index,
        open=rec1['open'],
        high=rec1['high'],
        low=rec1['low'],
        close=rec1['close'])

    return {'data': [data],

            'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(rec1.index), max(rec1.index)],
                     linecolor='white',
                     linewidth=2,
                     gridcolor='white'
                     ),

          yaxis=go.YAxis(dict(range=[min(rec1.low) - 5, max(rec1.high) + 5],
                              linecolor='white',
                              linewidth=2,
                              gridcolor='white'
                              )
                         ),
         title='BNB Price',
         plot_bgcolor='white',
         paper_bgcolor='white',
         font={'color': 'black'},
         legend={'orientation': "h", 'x': .1, 'y': -.2}
         )
}




if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(app.server, host="localhost", port=8080)
```

ive also tried to change ports, but that also doesnt help.

Any suggestions as to how i could solve this matter?

Best regards.

Mathias.

Answer (score 1):

You should target the `n_intervals` property of the `Interval` component in your callback (you targeted `n_interval`, i.e. you seem to be missing an ‘s’).

Comment: Awesome thanks, it was silly of me to miss that, it works and everything updates as it should. 
Thanks for the help.